# Increase Flash script execution time (FlasCC)

Tags: flash, actionscript, loading, alchemy, flascc

I am using FlasCC. My app works fine but takes long to load. I get a message that it has exceeded 15 seconds (Error #1502). How can I make this time longer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you [can't increase the max timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568206/disabling-script-max-execution-time-in-flex).

The long answer is that you can work around it:

1. If you're doing a lot of computation in your FlasCC code

   1. You could break up your execution into smaller "chunks" [that get called asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350319/loading-progress-for-long-loop-in-flex).
   2. You could use pthreads within your FlasCC C code (FP 11.5+)
2. You could put your FlasCC instance into a Worker thread (FP 11.4+)

Answer (score 1):

If you use mxmlc for compiling swf, you can use option 'max-execution-time'

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the max timeout for your local testing purposes. Check out how to [set the ScriptStuckTimeout variable in mms.cfg](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/flascc/docs/Reference.html#section_gdb).

Note that if your program exceeds even the extended timeout that you specify, Flash player will still show a message saying "exceeded 15 seconds", even though in fact it was waiting for longer.